# Remove tutorial projects from learn tab in Unity

Tags: unity

In Unity I downloaded one of the tutorial projects in the learn tab. However I don't need it anymore. What should I do to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example tutorials are located in:

### windows:

C:\Users{Username}\AppData\Roaming\Unity\Asset Store-5.x\Unity Technologies\Unity EssentialsSample Projects

### mac

C:\Users{Username}\Library\Unity\Asset Store-5.x\Unity Technologies

(You need to delete them manually)

Comment: As a related tangent, this location (well, the file path up to "Unity Technologies") is where all stuff downloaded from the Asset Store goes, not just the learning tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the other answer:

**On Linux:**

~/.local/share/unity3d/Asset Store-5.x/Unity Technologies/Project/